# Function assigning variables to array

Tags: c++, arrays, function

Im working on a programming assignment for school, 
(Simply need help with a part of my original code, not a homework solver, thanks.)
and my function, findHighest() is not working appropriately. Instead of the array storing the double values being passed to it, i believe it just has zeros. 
I need help remedying this. 
Thanks

```
int main()
{
double nEast = 0, sEast = 0, nWest = 0, sWest = 0;

cout << "\n\n\t\tQuarterly Sales Report by region\n";

cout << "\n\nNorth East region:\n" ;
nEast = getSales(nEast);
cout << "\n\nSouth East region:\n";
sEast = getSales(sEast);
cout << "\n\nNorth West region:\n";
nWest = getSales(nWest);
cout << "\n\nSouth West region:\n";
sWest = getSales(sWest);

findHighest(nEast, sEast, nWest, sWest);

return 0;
}




void findHighest (double nEast, double sEast, double nWest, double sWest)
{
double regions[4] = {nEast, sEast, nWest, sWest};
double temp = 0;


for(int i = 0; i <= 3;)
{
    if(regions[i] >= temp)
    {
        temp = regions[i];
        cout << temp;
        i++;
    }
}
cout << "The biggest number is: " << temp << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why do you increment your `i` in a weird place?

Comment: Why does he increment his i at all...

Comment: Have you verified that right before calling `findHighest`, the variables are set to what you expect them to be?

Comment: @Isaiah: If `i` were not incremented, the loop would not terminate.

Comment: Your `i` loop is infinite if the regions are not sorted in ascending order already

Comment: @icktoofay oh is that just a C++ thing? In other languages a for loop increments its own vars. Otherwise isnt it just a while?

Comment: @Isaiah: In all C-like languages, a `for` loop does not automatically increment the counter. Indeed, `for` adds no functionality a `while` loop could not do.

Comment: @icktoofay huh. Somethin new every day.

Comment: `for (X;Y;Z)` is equivalent to `X; while(Y) { .... Z; }`, if you don't use any `continue` statements

Comment: Oh, ok. I see. Eh, I think I like Java better.

Comment: @Isaiah: Java falls into the family of C-like languages, requiring you to increment manually. Maybe you just didn't notice it because it was in the first line of the loop rather than the last. The initial question was why the code in the question incremented it in the `if`, rather than in the first line as you'd expect.

Comment: oooohhhhh.... lol i feel like an idiot now. Haha I see. Its just a syntax thing. Same structure of course. :D

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

void findHighest( double nEast, double sEast, double nWest, double sWest )
{
   std::cout << "The biggest number is: " 
             << std::max( { nEast, sEast, nWest, sWest } )  << std::endl;
}
```

Or you can write

```
void findHighest( double nEast, double sEast, double nWest, double sWest )
{
   double max = nEast;
   if ( max < sEast ) max = sEast;
   if ( max < nWest ) max = nWest;
   if ( nax < sWest ) max = sWest;

   std::cout << "The biggest number is: " 
             << max  << std::endl;
}
```

Or another solution using an array

```
void findHighest( double nEast, double sEast, double nWest, double sWest )
{
   double regions[] = { nEast, sEast, nWest, sWest };       

   double max = regions[0];
   for ( double x : regions )
   {
      if ( max < x ) max = x;
   }

   std::cout << "The biggest number is: " 
             << max  << std::endl;
}
```

The first and the third solutions are based on features of the C++ 2011. However in the third solution you can simply substitute the range based for statement for ordinary for loop. It is your assignment.:)

Comment: You should indicate that the first solution [needs C++11 support](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max).

Comment: And so does the last.

Comment: @vlad_from_Moscow Thanks for the assistance. I actually solved it without using an array, but I wanted to know how to do it with an array.